# Get object values without using Object.values()

Tags: javascript

I *just* started learning to code and am working on this challenge. Having issues finding any relevant guidance online. Thanks in advance.

```
function keys(json) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    let result = [];
    for (const key in obj) {
        result.push(key);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I got this to work for returning keys without using Object.keys and I sort of assumed I could just swap the 'key' for 'value' but that didn't work.

```
function keys(json) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    var values = Object.keys(obj).map((key,value)=>{ values.push(value) });
    return values;
}
```

Also tried this, but I don't really understand the map function yet.

Comment: [`Object.keys`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an Array of keys. If you want values, you’d use [`Object.values`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead. Consider using [`Object.entries`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). The [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback accepts the value of one array item as the first parameter and its index as its second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const obj = {a:3, b:4}

const result = []
for (const key in obj) {
  result.push(obj[key])
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you get an array of keys (own, enummerable) of the array. for mapping values, you need to take a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with object and key.

```js
function values(json) {
    const object = JSON.parse(json);
    return Object
        .keys(object)
        .map(key => object[key]);
}

console.log(values('{"foo":"bar","baz":42}'));
```